# Vue: TypeError: _vm.myFunction is not a function

Tags: vue.js, button, events, event-handling

I am trying to add a simple button in a `.vue` file to log something to the console with this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="sayHello()">Click me</button> 
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
  },
  methods: {
    sayHello: function () {
      console.log('Hello!')
    }
  },
};
```

I get the following errors in the console:

```
TypeError: _vm.sayHello is not a function
```

and

```
Property or method "sayHello" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

I have seen some tutorials saying that you should add it to data, but it just says that `sayHello()` is undefined,  or when I define `sayHello()` in `data`, it says `sayHello()` is defined but never used.

I have even tried just doing the following:

```
<button v-on:click="console.log('Hello!')">Click me</button>
```

but it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
```

Can someone please help me with this? It's probably something super obvious that I haven't tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't close tag `<script>` after `export default { ... }`.

And I edited syntax for better readability.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="sayHello">Click me</button> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  methods: {
    sayHello() {
      console.log('Hello!');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

For the `click` events not necessarily a need to call a method with `()`. But though both variants are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

```
wrong
v-on:click="sayHello()" 


correctly
v-on:click="sayHello"
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="sayHello">Click me</button> 
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
  },
  methods: {
    sayHello () {
      console.log('Hello!')
    }
  },
}
```